# rsyslogd and characters #012 and #015

Tags: rsyslog

I use rsyslogd version 5.8.
The characters \n and \r are dumped as #012 and #015 in the log file.

Example (by entering command: printf "example-test[\r]" | logger) :

```
<13> 2014-07-07T11:01:03.254 root:  example-test[#015]
```

I would rather like to dump them in hexadecimal: #0A and #0D (or other more human-readable format).

How could I do this by modifying the rsyslogd configuration file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After reading the source code of rsyslogd versions 5.8.3 and 7.6.0, it appears that :

- the hexadecimal base cannot be used, as the octal base (#012, #015) is hard-coded.
- the escaping can be turned on or off: parameters $EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive and 
  $Escape8BitCharactersOnReceive

The documentation confirms that:

https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/configuration/input_directives/rsconf1_escapecontrolcharactersonreceive.html

https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/configuration/input_directives/rsconf1_escape8bitcharsonreceive.html

Comment: **Note:** turning on this option most probably destroys non-western character sets (like Japanese, Chinese and Korean) and it destroys digital signatures if such exists inside the message. Also the *drop-cc*, *space-cc* and *escape-cc* property replacer options do not work as expected because control characters are already removed upon message reception. If you intend to use these property replacer options, you must turn off `$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive`.